# hide caret (text cursor) on contenteditable div in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have contenteditable div on which i have file drop and copy-paste image event.
By using the color:transparent i am able to hide the blinking cursor on chrome browser. but in IE i came to know "The color of the text cursor in an input on IE is always the inverse of the background color".
Source:[How do I change the color of the text cursor in an input field in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684972/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-text-cursor-in-an-input-field-in-ie)

Is there any alternative way to disable a cursor or change the speed of blinking cursor so it looks like hidden in IE.

Comment: Have you tried `cursor: none` on the element? This would work across all browsers.

Comment: The property "cursor: none " is for disappearing the mouse pointer cursor. I need to hide the blinking cursor which usually in textbox/textarea or contenteditable div.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it in CSS with:

```
caret-color: transparent
```

Doesn't work in IE though. Here is [browser support chart](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color).

Comment: True, but will still help others who end up here from a Google search

Comment: This was helpful, didn't search for IE and this what came up (first in google). This is exactly what I was searching for. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for the support chart as well.

Comment: and I am looking for an IE solution specifically and your answer is just a noizzze.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for IE with this hack:

```
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 0 #333333;
```

You can replace the color (`#333333`) with whatever text color you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean changing the caret cursor, otherwise known as the text cursor; there are solutions available, although support for IE is rather limited. 
Perhaps, if not already, you might find this of some use: [Hide textfield blinking cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671141/hide-textfield-blinking-cursor)